# HP Probook boots into a blank screen

Tags: boot, display, hp

I recently got a used HP Probook 6565b and have Ubuntu 16.10. When it boots up, I get the purple screen for about 2 seconds before the screen goes blank. I can hear the drums to prompt the password, so I know it's working. I close the top and the laptop goes into suspend, and when I open the top back up and hit power it restores to the normal log in screen. At that point ,there are no problems. But when I turn the computer off, I have to go through that same process (turn on, wait for drums, close top, restore from suspend, log in).